# Async coroutine doesn't seem to finish

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.6

Just poking my toe into asynchronous programming in Python, and ran into an interesting application for it where I need to gather file sizes on about 10 files each on ~100 machines to see which machines aren't purging their log files appropriately.

My synchronous approach was:

```
File_info = namedtuple("File_info", "machineinfo size")

machines = utils.list_machines()  # the computers being queried
# each machine object has attributes like "name", "IP", and "site_id" among others

file_sizes = {}
# {filename: [File_info, ...], ...}

for m in machines:
    print(f"Processing {m}...")  # this is "Processing {m}...".format(m=m)
                                 # isn't Python 3.6 awesome?!
    for path in glob.glob(f"//{m.IP}/somedir/*.dbf"):
        fname = os.path.split(path)[-1].lower()
        machineinfo = (m.site_id, m.name)
        size = os.stat(path).st_size
        file_sizes.setdefault(fname, []).append(File_info(registerinfo, size))
```

This works great, but takes a long time with the network operations pulling all those globs and stats. I wanted to use Python 3.5's async/await syntax with asyncio to asynchronize those calls. Here's what I came up with:

```
File_info = namedtuple("File_info", "machineinfo size")

machines = utils.list_machines()

file_sizes = {}
# {filename: [File_info, ...], ...}

async def getfilesizes(machine, loop):
    machineinfo = machine.site_id, machine.name
    paths = glob.glob(f"//{machine.IP}/somedir/*.dbf")
    coros = [getsize(path) for path in paths]
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coros))
    sizes = {fname: File_info(machineinfo, size) for (fname, size) in results}
    return sizes

async def getsize(path):
    return os.path.split(path)[-1], os.stat(path).st_size

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*(getfilesizes(m, loop) for m in machines)))
for result in results:
    file_sizes.update(result)
    # I have a problem here since my dict values are lists that need to extend
    # not overwrite, but that's not relevant for the error I'm getting
```

However the script hangs inside the outer `loop.run_until_complete` section. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A coroutine that wants to run another coroutine or get a future's result is supposed to `await` it, not submit it with `run_until_complete`.

Comment: Do I should `await asyncio.gather(...)`?

Comment: @user2357112 well I'll be a monkey's uncle, that was simple. Not sure why I didn't make the connection that `asyncio.gather` gives one `Future` object so I can just away it rather than scheduling it. Would you like to write that up as an answer? Otherwise I'll self-answer.

Comment: Go ahead and self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

A coroutine that wants to run another coroutine (as `getfilesizes` does with `getsize`) should `await` it rather than scheduling it in the event loop.

```
...

async def getfilesizes(machine):  # changed func sig
    machineinfo = machine.site_id, machine.name
    paths = glob.glob(f"//{machine.IP}/somedir/*.dbf")
    coros = [getsize(path) for path in paths]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*coros)  # await the results instead!
    sizes = {fname: File_info(machineinfo, size) for (fname, size) in results}
    return sizes

...
```

Since `asyncio.gather` creates one Future from any number of coroutines, this `await` functionally acts on the whole group of coroutines and grabs all their results at once.